# Listview.builder Positioning a widget on another widget

Tags: android, ios, flutter, user-interface, android-listview

I'm trying to make an application like Instagram. But I can't fully view the zoomed picture because of other pictures.

**Codes:**

```
List colors = [
    Colors.green,
    Colors.blue,
    Colors.red,
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Demo"),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 3,
        itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
          TransformationController controller = TransformationController();
          return Container(
            child: InteractiveViewer(
              transformationController: controller,
              onInteractionEnd: (_) {
                setState(() {
                  controller.toScene(Offset.zero);
                });
              },
              child: ColorFiltered(
                colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(colors[index], BlendMode.color),
                child: FlutterLogo(),
              ),
            ),
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

**Note:** I can't use widgets like stack because of listview.builder

Answer (score 0):

You could either use Visibility widget or Opacity widget to change the visibility of images not being currently panned. Please see the code below I'm using AnimatedOpacity just so that the disappearance of the images does not look too sudden, but you may use Opacity widget as well.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Flutter Demo")),
        body: MyStatefulWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  static List colors = [
    Colors.green,
    Colors.blue,
    Colors.red,
  ];
  final List<double> _opacity = List.generate(colors.length, (index) => 1);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Demo"),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 3,
        itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
          final TransformationController controller =
              TransformationController();
          return AnimatedOpacity(
            opacity: _opacity[index],
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
            child: Container(
              child: InteractiveViewer(
                transformationController: controller,
                onInteractionStart: (details) {
                  for (int i = 0; i < _opacity.length; i++) {
                    _opacity[i] = i == index ? 1 : 0;
                  }
                  setState(() {});
                },
                onInteractionEnd: (_) {
                  setState(() {
                    _opacity.fillRange(0, _opacity.length, 1);
                    controller.toScene(Offset.zero);
                  });
                },
                child: ColorFiltered(
                  colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(colors[index], BlendMode.color),
                  child: const FlutterLogo(),
                ),
              ),
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your opinion is brilliant, but I want the zoomed image to be on top of the other visible images. Thank you for your reply though.